# change height of text

Tags: line-spacing

I am writing some text that spans over two lines. At the end of the first line there is `$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} u_n=0$`. I am using the `\limits` command for better effect, but it increases the space between the lines (normal behavior).

However, I would like it not to, as the second line ends before this could be a problem.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to make the height of that math command 'phantom' (I remember doing it years ago), but I can't remember/find how.

Comment: is there a mathjax or similar plugin here ?

Comment: Try `$\smash{\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} u_n=0}$`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No we do not have MathJaX plugin here, because we're primarily interested in the TeX code itself.

Comment: @Alex : That did the trick ! thank you. Don't remember using this last time though. If you post this as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: @Alex -- slightly better, perhaps: `\smash[b]{...}`; requires `amsmath`.

Comment: The reason for not using `\limits` is just that it increases the line spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : can't say I see a difference. what does the [b] do ? egreg : Yeah I know, but I'm only using it where line spacing is not an issue.

Comment: @imj -- the `[b]` (bottom) limits the smashing to what's below the baseline.  in this instance it really doesn't make a difference, but there are times when it's important to influence just what's below (or above, with `[t]`) the line to avoid collisions with something in an adjacent line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex pointed out, `$\smash{\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} u_n=0}$` works perfectly. Using the optional argument `[b]` (`$\smash[b]{...}$`) limits the smashing to what's below the baseline (thx barbara beeton, that became relevant to me later on).